# Kibana query on NESTED object returns estimated price why?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana, aggregation, kibana-6

In Kibana visualization I built a bar chart graph that aggregates orders per label bucket (e.g: USD/CAD). Then I display the sum of orders price per bucket for each of the orders inside it.

My chart visualization returns a wrong price which seems to be coming approximated

[image]

This is my graph query request debug

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "3": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "label.keyword",
        "size": 2,
        "order": {
          "_term": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "orders.id",
            "size": 40,
            "order": {
              "1": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "1": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "orders.price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "docvalue_fields": [],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the response, which confirms the the `orders.price` value is being approximated

```
{
  "took": 9,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 124,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "3": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 122,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "2": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213481,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213482,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213483,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213484,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213485,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213486,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213487,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213488,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213489,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213490,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213491,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213492,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213493,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213494,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213495,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213496,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213497,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213498,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213499,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213500,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213501,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213502,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213503,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213504,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213505,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213506,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213507,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213508,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213509,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213510,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213511,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213512,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213513,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213514,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213515,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213516,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213517,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213518,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213519,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.003690590019687079
                },
                "key": 213520,
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          "key": "IOST/ETH",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "2": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213321,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213322,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213323,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213324,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213325,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213326,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213327,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213328,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213329,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213330,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213331,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213332,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213333,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213334,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213335,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213336,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213337,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213338,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213339,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213340,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213341,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213342,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213343,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213344,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213345,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213346,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213347,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213348,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213349,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213350,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213351,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213352,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213353,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213354,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213355,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213356,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213357,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213358,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213359,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "1": {
                  "value": 0.0003004000000146334
                },
                "key": 213360,
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          "key": "IOST/BTC",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "status": 200
```

And discovery tab confirms that my data is there and should be retrieving the right price from the `order.price`

What is more strange is, when I flatten my data and stop using an array of nested orders the same graph will work. Am I doing anything wrong while building my graph? I need to fix this because my source data comes in that structure,  it has a nested array of orders for each label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orders field has to be mapped as a nested type for you to get accurate results.

```
"mappings": {
            "orderbook": {
                "properties": {
                    "exchange": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "label": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "length": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "orders": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "label": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "price": {
                                "type": "float"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "timestamp": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In Kibana then you can use vega like this

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
  "title": "Order Totals vs Order Ids",
  "data": {
    "url": {
      "index": "orderbookindex",
      "body": {
        "size": 0,
        "aggs": {
          "Orders": {
            "nested": {"path": "orders"},
            "aggs": {
              "Order_Ids": {
                "terms": {"field": "orders.id"},
                "aggs": {
                  "Order_Totals": {
                    "sum": {"field": "orders.price"}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "format": {
      "property": "aggregations.Orders.Order_Ids.buckets"
    }
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "bin": false,
      "field": "key",
      "type": "Nominal",
      "axis": {"title": "Order Ids"}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Order_Totals.value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"title": "Order Totals"}
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

I haven't tried the other layer of grouping but you would need something like this https://bl.ocks.org/domoritz/f5abc519dd990bfcbc3f20f634658364

There is also a plugin available for handling nested aggregations in Kibana for you to try
https://github.com/ppadovani/KibanaNestedSupportPlugin

-------------- Solution Output ----------------------------------

Guid's output from @sramalingam24 Vega code

[image]

Comment: wow! thanks man this seems awsome. I'll try and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: Great, let me know

Comment: Hey man, thanks again! It worked perfect, you helped me a lot!! Vega seems to be very powerful, thanks also for introducing me to it. After this, I have now 2 questions related to it if you don't mind ehehehe. First one, indeed I had to change my orders to nested type and it worked, I didn't even notice before my orders vector was from the type object. But the question is, what is the real difference between nested types and objects types. I mean, if both represent a vector of objects, the only difference is the possibility to access its properties?

Comment: And the second, it relates to the new picture of the output I got above from Vega. As you can see in the picture the graph is showing only 
 the first 10 orders I have inside the Nested type orders, shouldn't it show the 40 orders I have inside it? Is there anything I could do to add the 40 orders to the graph?

Comment: The difference between object and nested type especially when you have arrays is explained here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: That is controlled by the size factor (by default first 10 is returned).

Comment: Hey  man @sramalingam24, I was trying to build a chart in Vega based on your example but I am having trouble to figure out how to format properties for a multiple buckets aggregation query. Would you know what to do in this case here in this new post [New Post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50339671/kibana-vega-how-to-build-multi-view-chart-aggregating-multiple-buckets)

Comment: Hmm I am not quite sure, you may want to ask on the Vega help forum/mailing list on how to display nested json structure.